# Regular expression that accept only excel-like range of row or column cells

Tags: c#, regex

I want to know a regular expression that accepts only excel-like range of row or column cells in C#

For example,

A2:D2 - OK
A23:F23 - OK
A3:D6 - fail

or

A1:A12 - OK
A1:C1 - fail

Comment: Why use a regex to validate it? Once you've got the parts, a couple of lines of code would do it and would be much easier to a) write and b) understand.

Comment: You can use backreferences `([A-Z]+)(\d+):(\1\d+|[A-Z]+\2)`. But this just validates the shape. So B3:A3 would still pass, and has to be checked afterwards.

Comment: Why would A1:C1 fail when A2:D2 passes?

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension class, you can create some tests with `Regex` and with testing code to validate the range strings:

```
public static class ExcelRangeExt {
    static Regex excelRangeRE = new Regex(@"[A-Z]+[0-9]+:[A-Z]+[0-9]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    static Regex betweenPosRE = new Regex(@"(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public static bool IsExcelRange(this string r) => excelRangeRE.IsMatch(r);
    public static bool IsExcelRowOrCol(this string r) {
        var valid = excelRangeRE.IsMatch(r);
        if (valid) {
            var splitr = r.Split(':').Select(s => betweenPosRE.Split(s)).ToList();
            valid = splitr[0][0] == splitr[1][0] // is column
                    || splitr[0][1] == splitr[1][1]; // is row
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

So you can test a single range string by calling `IsExcelRowOrCol`:

```
var valid = rangeStr.IsExcelRowOrCol();
```